# Splitting an Enterprise project (ex. ERP) to multiple small projects (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, project, enterprise

Is it an excellent way to split an Enterprise project such as ERP software into multiple small projects?

Our ERP project has some modules:

- HRM
- Sales & Marketing
- Production Planning
- Procurement
- Inventory & Warehouse
- ...

Is it a proper way to have one project for each module? (with one database for all modules)

[image]

Comment: Could you please share us what each module contains? Altough, its completely depends on requirements however, of course its always recommeded to split the project into `smaller class files` furthermore, the architecture should be `loosely coupled`. In addition, you could have a look few [`architectural pattern here in our official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures)

Comment: Like SAP ERP modules, each module can be a stand-alone program: Inventory & Warehouse Management, Sales & Marketing, Accounting, etc. I'd like to know if it is a proper way to create an ASP.NET Core MVC project for each module.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to know if it is a proper way to create an ASP.NET Core MVC
> project for each module.

Well, based on your reply, if `each module` means `class files` of your project `HRM`, `Sales & Marketing` then that wouldn't be sopt on. Standard [`asp.net core project`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#traditional-n-layer-architecture-applications) could be designed like below:

[image]

However, project architecture completely evolve depending on over the time so its quite challenging to say what is within the sound.

Nevertheless, few generic way followed by the developer these days are as below:

**Architecture You Can Follow:**

1. [Clean Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#clean-architecture)
2. [Onion Architecture](https://jeffreypalermo.com/2008/07/the-onion-architecture-part-1/)
3. [Repository Pattern](https://deviq.com/design-patterns/repository-pattern)

**Principle You Should Consider:**

No matter, which Architecture you have opted to implement, therefore, two things you must consider:

1. [SOLID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/may/csharp-best-practices-dangers-of-violating-solid-principles-in-csharp)
2. [DRY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/architectural-principles#dont-repeat-yourself-dry)

**Note:** If you want to create single project therefore, the class files, and other related stuff, for all of your `module` `server cost` would considerably be surged. We must bear in mind the cost and maintainability as well.